# Unable to pass props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I wrote a react site about 6 months ago and had a suite of Jest tests, which all ran fine. I've created a second project based off this one but for some reason when I try and write the same tests on basic component rendering, they fail.

The error I get is

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(ControlBar)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(ControlBar)".

I've done some reading around and there are a few posts on similar topics, which seem to say that TypeScript/Redux aren't playing well together. However in my last project it was exactly the same as above and all the tests run fine. So not sure if it is just that I have pulled in a newer version of something which causes this breaking change, but hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong?

My component

```
interface IControlBarProps {
    includeValidated: boolean, 
    includeValidatedChanged: (includeValidated:boolean) => void,
}

export class ControlBar extends React.Component<IControlBarProps, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {    
        super(props);                
      }

    public render() { ... }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: IStoreState) {
  return {
    includeValidated: state.trade.includeValidated
  };
}    

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    includeValidatedChanged: (includeValidated:boolean) => {
        dispatch(getIncludeValidatedChangedAction(includeValidated))      
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ControlBar);
```

My test

```
import ControlBar from '../ControlBar';

describe('Control Bar Component', () => {

  it('should render without throwing an error', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ControlBar includeValidated={true} includeValidatedChanged={() => {return;}} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('div.Control-bar').exists()).toEqual(true);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import ControlBar component wrapped with Redux (export default). To unit test ControlBar try

```
import { ControlBar } from '../ControlBar';
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Fairly new to React so the distinction between different exports wasn't something I was aware of but that worked. Could you suggest a good place that explains about different types of exports?

Comment: It is actually realy simple. Every *.js file should have only one default export. When you import some component/function without curly brackets you basically import component marked as default. Otherwise when you want to import specific or multiple components you should use import with curly brackets i.e. `import { ControlBar, ScrollBar } from '../Bars.`.  It is JS ES6 feature, not React.

Answer (score 2):

Import your component not connected to Redux, the named export, not the default export of the connected one.

```
import { ControlBar } from '../ControlBar';
```